# Alesis DM10 (2011) with Logic Pro x

Tags: software, logic-pro

I have a Alesis DM10 (2011 model) connected to my MacPro via USB and my Logic Pro X sees the DM10 and is getting inputs as I can see the sound bars moving, but obviously I am not getting any sound as I need to get a sound pack.

This is my question

Which sound pack should I get ? I have seen various ones EZdrummer, Superior Drummer, BFD etc.

I am mainly going to be using it at home for my own stuff with friends etc but would like the best quality for the best price of course or if someone has any better ideas.

I would also like to be able to add further sounds such as orchestral drums, world sounds etc for some projects I might like to do.

Comment: imnsho, EZdrummer would be easiest to handle, Superior best overall [but with a lot more work] & I haven't looked at BFD in years, I never liked their over-processed sounds, personally.

Comment: imnsho thanx for that, ill have a further look into EZdrummer, there website didnt really give me much to go by as it looked like it was more for musicians who need basic drums, ill see if there is a trial or something to play with

Comment: Hi @AJHenderson Yes I have been on the Video Production, im also a amateur musso, I didnt see a group for music practice and theory but I could have just missed it, cheers for pointing it out, but I will be using my drums for doing simple scores for my films as well as making music etc, but I will head over there and ask the question but the EZdrummer looks good but I found a comparison with EZdrum and SupDrums

Answer (score 1):

Any VST drums that you buy will work with DM10 module. It's all a matter of your budget I think, especially if you don't plan to do it professionally. My personal favourite is EZDrummer 2 which is ultra-easy, has great sounds and it's one of the cheapest VST drums on the market. It also has a compability mode for Alesis drum modules which will help you overcome some of the annoyances of the module.

I've written posts about this on my blog [here](http://rajchel.pl/2014/12/triggering-ezdrummer-with-alesis-dm10/) and [here](http://rajchel.pl/2015/01/triggering-ezdrummer-with-dm10-round-two/).

I'm personally very happy about this setup. The EZD2 samples are great. If I was to point of the feature I'd like to add to EZD2 is to have the possibility to edit the assignment of MIDI notes to drum kit parts. But from what I was able to find out it's only possible in Superior Drummer 2 and BFD3 which are much more expensive. I've also worked with Superior Drummer and while this software has much more possibilities that EZD I found out that I wasn't using most of them anyway.

The feature that is my favourite in EZD2 is by far the Song Builder, which allows you to fine tune the midi patters and generate the whole song structure based on the single MIDI pattern. That's great for recording as you can have a basic drum track done in 5 minutes and focus on recording guitars and vocals and at the end you can sit back and finish polishing the drum track.

Comment: Wow had a quick read through and you seems to have written a thorough blog post/s. Ill give it a try when I get some time to sit and configure it all, first things first is getting EZDrummer2

Comment: Hi, I have tried EZdrummer 2 and it is great but due to issues I cannot afford to buy it yet, I have tried to use the LPX built in sounds but I loose 2nd floor tom, 1 cymbal and I cannot get it to separate into individual tracks without having to spend just as much time renaming and sorting copying them into new tracks, any advice ?